# How to handle php webservice response android?

Tags: android

I am working on android application and getting the data from php webservice. Before calling the php webservice, I am checking for internet connection. If connection is there then only the asynchronous task will start. But here I am getting another issue i.e after checking for internet connection and while executing the background task in asynchronous method sometimes the power is going suddenly and at that time the crash is coming. But actually I took a boolean variable and kept server=false if the try action is not executed. But when there is no internet connection when posting paramaeters to php it is not going to catch method and so it is not displaying the toast message as "Try again". Please tell me where actually I went wrong.

```
My code:

boolean server = true;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
                    LongOperation1 op = new LongOperation1();
                    op.execute("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
}


private void loadFeed()

    {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("val1",value1));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("val2",value2));


        try {
            response = CustomHttpClient
                    .executeHttpPost(
                            "http://....................../file.php",
                            postParameters);
            System.out.println("the ultimate response" + response);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            server = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }

    private class LongOperation1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            loadFeed();
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog1.dismiss();
            try {

                if (server) {


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(Reuse.this, "Please wait...",
                    "Retrieving data ...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the logcat and point out the line,where exception is thrown.

Comment: are you getting `e.printStackTrace();` printed in `catch` clause?

Comment: hi yes i am getting the stacktrace but when i am trying to print the server value in catch block it is not printing

Comment: hi i am getting socket exception at the line response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://....................../file.php",postParameters);